# Good chess opening for a beginner

Tags: opening, beginner

I am a beginner and my chess opening is pretty weak. Can you suggest me an opening that is easy to learn and is suitable for a beginner like me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good openings for a beginner (for white)](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/1960/good-openings-for-a-beginner-for-white)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it stands now, your post will be marked as duplicate, so I will answer fast before it is closed.

> Can you suggest me an opening that is easy to learn and is suitable for a beginner like me?

This is very hard to do, because your opponent will **always** have chance to play the move that transposes into different opening. Studying seriously openings **will limit your development** because you don't know which style suits you. **That should be your main goal -> to "discover" your style, to find out what suits you and what not.**

To achieve this, you need to learn **basic** endgames first, tactics second and then typical middlegame positions.

At your level of skill, you just need to **survive** the opening relying on **general opening principles.** Your goal will be to leave the opening **with equal position.**

Just play **any** opening that you find **interesting**, and experiment. **Try them all out, don't be afraid!** Once you find out which opening suits you, ask a question about it here and we shall further help you.

This was the best thing I ever did when I was a beginner! I found a partner that was way stronger than me, but was willing to teach me by playing with me. I tried all sorts of openings against him until I found those that I had "natural gift" for. Maybe you have talent for closed openings or open games, but you will find that out only by trying out different openings.

So remember:

1. **Learn basic opening principles!**
2. **Play everything**, there is enough online documentation on any opening for a beginner level ( ask here for help if you get stuck )!
3. Work **very hard** on tactics!

For now, this is enough. Once you feel confident in your skills ( once you estimate that you have improved enough for intermediate level ) come back here and ask us for further advice.

Good luck, young grasshopper! :)

Comment: @Abhishekstudent: Just follow my advice, and do not be afraid to ask further questions here. You will be just fine! Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

With white start with 1.e4 and study open games, something like the Italian or Scotch game, later the Ruy Lopez.

Of course black will try also Sicilian, French or Caro-Kan. You have to know something about all of this: so for Sicilian study at least 1.e4 c5  2.c3, for French and Caro-Kan the advance 1.e4 e6 2.d4 d5 3.e5 and 1.e4 c6 2.d4 d5 3.e5.

Another option is to play 1.Nf3 and forget about any study of the openings. You will spend time in the first moves, but few people at lower levels have any idea about why on earth you did not push a pawn as first move.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend the KIA(King's Indian Attack). It is very easy to learn and it is very good for beginner play.