# Which piece should I move and where should I move it when playing against black in chess when I have the first move of the game?

Tags: opening, strategy, beginner

What is the first piece I should move as a novice chess player when beginning the game on the white side as a defensive strategy?

Comment: See also: http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/1960/good-openings-for-a-beginner-for-white

Comment: You are white, you go first and black can't threaten you in any way yet. Why think of defense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no magical move that will solve your opening problems. But if you learn **opening principles** you can find the correct moves for solving your problems your own.

I recommend you to read this: http://www.chess.com/article/view/the-principles-of-the-opening

I also found this video quite entertaining: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNO9KCloLRE

Also check these **opening traps**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chess_traps

Comment: IMO, learning some "basic rules of thumb" (such as the well-written principles of the opening linked in this answer) is a great way to "jump start" learning.  They're not going to be right every game, but just having them in mind will improve a beginner's play drastically.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to play "defensively" as White, start with 1. Nf3. a) This develops a piece. b) It delays moving a pawn, and gives Black a chance to "commit" first. c) It prevents Black from playing e5 without further preparation. d) It starts preparing for castling king side.

Your next move is to move a pawn, probably g3. Then move the light squared bishop to g2. Then you can castle, O-O, with a maximally secure king side, protected by both a knight and a bishop.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.There are tons of openings and tons of variations that arise from them. So you may want to learn openings first to know what and what you might be comfortable with. Check out http://www.chessfiles.com/openings.html for openings and variations. They are available in PGN format as well if you want to use it with a GUI. Have fun

Answer (score -1):

I have a strategy that works like this:

```
G1F3
B1C3
H2H4
A2A4
H1H3
A1A3
E2E4
D2D4
F1E2
C1D2
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As amusing as that is, I don't think that's the best opening for a beginner...

Comment: @Ghotir I don't see how it's amusing. If it is, it was not intended and I assure you it works for me, providing the opponent does not take the frontmost two pawns. Even if this occurs, it is still possible to win with this beginning strategy.

Comment: I meant no offense (and you'll note I did not vote down).  It's the development of the rooks I find amusing - in large part because it prevents White from castling, which can be an incredibly powerful tool.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I do not castle often (*gasp*) and so did not notice. :-) The reason I do this is to protect that line from attack by the black pieces, since they cannot move to anywhere along that line without protecton.

Comment: You have bishops moving sideways?

Comment: @Glorfindel I interpreted that to be F1E2 and C1D2 for the last two moves.  Only thing that made sense.

Comment: @Ghotir: This is a "beginner's" (but bona fide, if ineffective strategy).Someone tried to teach me a variation of this when I started out.

Comment: Oops. I did mean F1E2 and C1D2. Sorry about that.