# Attack Opening For White

Tags: opening, beginner, fried-liver-attack

I'm kinda new to chess and I'm trying to learn new openings that are aggressive.

I've used the *Fried Liver attack* many times. Are there any other opening(s) which are close to the *Fried Liver attack* that I could use?

Comment: Why are you trying to learn aggressive openings?

Comment: @Jossie so he can quickly take down the other player's army at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

**For white**

The Danish Gambit.

**For black**

A variation of the four knights with 4. Bc4 will lead to an opening of the game for black by the means of 4...Nxe4 5. Nxe4 d5.

Alternatively, 5. Bxf7+ Kxf7 6. Nxe4 may also occur with sharp play (although you do give up the bishop pair, Black also gave up his right to castle).

Related: [Very Aggressive Openings](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/75/very-aggressive-openings)

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with the Fried Liver attack, I recommend you the Evans Gambit.

1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bc4
3...... Nf6 is fried liver attack.
3....... Bc5 4 b4 leads to Evans.

If you are afraid of losing two pawns in the opening, try the Italian game which is similar to Evans.

Try green game, night at the opera etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can find similar Chess Openings .

1. The Evans gambit . (Play it if you love Tempos and initiative)
2. The Scotch
3. Max Lange Attack
4. Morphy Attack .
5. Philidor Central Attack

There are many more but you need to find it out for yourself.

You can find some good Chess Videos for the above .

[Max Lange Attack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMcDNVSXyd0)

[Morphy Attack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BrbChWI89ek)

[Philidor Central Attack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9I3Q0wBKvI)

[Scotch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldM0MirbodE)