# What is this opening/position called, and what is white’s best move?

Tags: opening, analysis

```
 [FEN "r1bqk2r/pppp1ppp/2n2n2/2b3B1/4P3/8/PPP2PPP/RN1QKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]
```

Do you know the name of this opening/position? Additionally, please tell me what white’s best move is in this position. I ask this because I play aggressively, and I need help with finding my next best move.

Comment: 2. Nf3 is the main move after 1. e4 e5.  You should probably play that unless you want the play the Danish Gambit as @Glorfindel suggested.

Comment: If you "play aggressively" why did you retreat your queen all the way to d1 when you could have put it on e3 or a4?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you arrived at this position with the moves

```
[FEN ""]
[StartPly "10"]

1. e4 e5 2. d4 exd4 3. Qxd4 Nc6 4. Qd1 Nf6 5. Bg5 Bc5
```

White is already worse here because you're behind in development. There's no reason to have your queen chased around like that; therefore, it sees very little play and the position does not have a name. If you want to play aggressively, play 3. c3 instead (the [Danish Gambit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_Gambit)), and there are plenty of aggressive options after 2. Nf3 as well. [This question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/358/7297) lists more options you might be interested in.

Right now, you should concentrate on completing your development, e.g. with 6. Nc3. Playing aggressive moves in this very position will for sure lead to a quick defeat.

Comment: If this is the move order, then it's the **Center Game**. Playable, but Qc8 is just a mistake. Qe3 is the best move. Nepomniatchi is playing that sometimes.